# window.open sends the current window to 0

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

On a page (we'll call it: *domain.com/subdirectory/page.html*) I have a link like this:
`<a href="javascript:window.open('someurl','_blank');">Link</a>`

The new window opens perfectly, but the problem is, the pre-existing window gets redirected to *{domain.com}/{subdirectory}/0* and I can't figure out why it's adding the 0 to the subdirectory and trying to go there.

I have tried moving the window.open to the onclick and making the href "void(0)" and even changed it to a span with an onclick, but I get the same results no matter which option I try. All I want is for the new window to pop up and for nothing to happen to the page you're already on.

The same thing happens in IE9 and in Chrome.

The reason I am using the window.open and not target="_blank" is because I also want to remove the menu and other stuff from that window to save space.

**Answer Discovered**
When I summarized the problem, I simplified my code too much as to make it impossible for anyone to answer (not by intention of course). I apologize for this.

Here's the actual window.open command (minus the URL): `window.open('[hidden url]'_blank',height='400px',width='450px',location=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0);`

The problem was the "location=0". When I read a tutorial on window.open, it said to set this to 0 if I didn't want the URL shown. Personally, I didn't care, but I figured, the more real estate for information display the better. As it turns out, "location" is a URL and not a boolean property.

Once I removed the "location=0" it began functioning as expected/desired.

Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Can you post more of the HTML markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I summarized the problem, I simplified my code too much as to make it impossible for anyone to answer (not by intention of course). I apologize for this.

Here's the actual window.open command (minus the URL): `window.open('[hidden url]'_blank',height='400px',width='450px',location=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0);`

The problem was the `location=0`. When I read a tutorial on `window.open`, it said to set this to 0 if I didn't want the URL shown. Personally, I didn't care, but I figured, the more real estate for information display the better. As it turns out, `location` is a URL and not a boolean property.

Once I removed the `location=0` it began functioning as expected/desired.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it in an onclick event. You need to also add in `return false;` to stop the browser from following the link.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('someurl','_blank'); return false;">Link</a>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56jJv/3/) of it working.

[Here's another, slightly cleaner way to do it](http://jsfiddle.net/56jJv/1/):

```
<a id="link" href="#">Link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var link = document.getElementById("link");

    link.onclick = function() {
        window.open('someurl','_blank');
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I don't know your scenario, but this is probably the ideal way to do it:

```
<a target="_blank" href="someurl">Link</a>
```

Clean and simple, and it does the exact same thing.

Comment: Did you add `return false;`? That's the important part. As you can see from the fiddles, this does in fact work. If it's not working for you, something else in your code is messing up.

Answer (score 1):

Use an onclick and return false from the event handler:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('someurl','_blank'); return false;">Link</a>
```

I also recommend separating your Javascript from your HTML. If you just have the one link you could do something like:

```
<a id="linkid" href="someurl" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Then somewhere before your closing `</body>` tag and after that link tag:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('linkid').onclick = function(){
      window.open('someurl','_blank');
      return false;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I already tried the first option to no avail. I do not just have the one link though. The page is generated dynamically based on a database, so there could be hundreds by the end.

Comment: @Michael If you have many use should give the ones that you want to use `window.open` for a class and then select all elements with that class and do the same thing. May I ask why you need to use `window.open` and can't just use an `<a>` tag with the `target="blank"` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to learn JavaScript. Its really powerful and the basic things aren't very hard to learn.
There is an JavaScript object named window with an attribute (variable) called location. That is the URL of your page so, with the `window.open(..., location = 0, ...);` you were setting the URL of the page you wanted to open as `http://the_page_you_are_calling_from_url/0`.
So... yes, you were correct that location was the problem.

If you wish, take a look at [Mozilla window API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window)